# How to decompress a jpeg with swift that was compressed with UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_) -> NSData?

Tags: ios, swift, compression

I'm using UIImageJPEGRepresentation(...) to compress images before I store them on a server.  My problem is when I am retrieving them from the server I need a way to decompress them in order to display the image again.  How would I go about this using swift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as creating a `UIImage` from the `NSData` representing the image

```
//imageData is the JPEG compressed data retrieved from your server

if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
    //do something with image
} else {
    //image is nil, do something else
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

you might be use below code:

```
let img = UIImage(data: serverData) // serverdata means get response to server side
```